# Apache pig ERROR org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.Launcher - Error: org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter$AppendWriteException:

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, avro

I am trying to load some data, filter by certain field and store the output to HDFS. My code looks like:

```
data = LOAD '$inputPath' using AvroStorage();
data = FILTER data by condition;
STORE data INTO '$outputPath'using AvroStorage('schema', '$SCHEMA');
```

But I am getting an error saying:

```
 ERROR org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.Launcher - Error: org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter$AppendWriteException: java.lang.NullPointerException: null of int of int in field id of com.stackoverflow.id
```

Can someone suggests what could be wrong? I am guessing it's because some of the fields read from HDFS are null and AvroStorage is not allowing this to happen? Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your avro schema is defining a field that doesn't allow null but your data contains a null.

Comment: Thanks! This may be the case most of the time. In my case there's some slight mismatch between the schema I have and the one on HDFS so make sure to check this if anyone is facing a similar problem.

Comment: Ah I see. I was wrong then.  I'm still new to this stackoverflow but in this case you didn't need to choose my answer?